# PHP array_filter return array keys

Tags: php, arrays, filter, key

I whant from this:

```
Array{
   [1] => Array{ [id] => 1, [name] => paul},
   [2] => Array{ [id] => 2, [name] => eva}
}
```

to get this:

```
Array{
   [1] => paul,
   [2] => eva
}
```

I used to array_filter function to achive this, but it returned the same array, that was inputted. What am i doing wrong?

```
array_filter($array, create_function('&$a','return $a["name"]);'));
```

P.S. I know i can use foreach, but i whant this a oneliner.

Comment: `array_filter` quite aptly *filters*, it doesn't *change* the elements in the array. You're looking for `array_map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `array_map()`, not `array_filter()`.
Somehow like this:

```
function func($a) {
    return $a["name"];
}
array_map('func', $array);
```

Comment: Ok, not a one liner though

Answer (score 2):

You need to use array_map() instead array_filter()
try

```
function cube($n)
{
    return($n * $n * $n);
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$b = array_map("cube", $a);
print_r($b);
```

More info:
http://www.php.net/array_map

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_combine](https://www.php.net/array_column) and [array_column](https://www.php.net/array_column)

`array_column()` Works if `php version` > =`PHP 5.5`

```
<?php

$a=array(array('id'=>"1",'name'=>"paul"),array('id'=>"2",'name'=>"eva"));

$a=array_combine(array_column($a,"id"),array_column($a,"name"));
print_r($a);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => paul
    [2] => eva
)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/98648)</kbd>

Comment: @hindmost yes i have added it my answer